# Can't ping other pods by hostname on minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kube-dns, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a statefulSet with two replicas.
It's headless service name is **"gov-svc"**
It's ->

1. .metadata.name: sts
2. .metadata.namespace: default
3. .spec.serviceName: gov-svc
4. .spec.template.spec.subdomain: gov-svc
5. .spec.replicas: 2

Before running statefulSet

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-99b9bb8bd-qdnsb                 1/1     Running            0          4h
kube-system   etcd-minikube                           1/1     Running            0          4h
kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube             1/1     Running            0          4h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-minikube                 1/1     Running            0          4h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-minikube        1/1     Running            1          4h
kube-system   kube-proxy-b9np6                        1/1     Running            0          4h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-minikube                 1/1     Running            0          4h
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-7db4dc666b-bsk8k   1/1     Running            0          4h
kube-system   storage-provisioner
```

After running both of the pods of this statefulSet, from pod `sts-0`, `ping` results:

```
$ ping  sts-0.gov-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
PING sts-0.gov-svc.default.svc.cluster.local (172.17.0.11): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.11: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.11: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.444 ms
^C
--- redis-cluster-exp-0-0.redis-cluster-exp.default.svc.cluster.local ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.051/0.247/0.444 ms
```

But when I try to `ping sts-1` from `sts-0`, it says:

```
$ ping sts-1.gov-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
ping: bad address 'sts-1.gov-svc.default.svc.cluster.local'
```

I need to ping other pods successfully by hostname. How can I do it?

Comment: What's your kubernetes version

Comment: my kubernetes version: 1.11.3

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma Hi.I know, It's been a year for this question but I am also facing this issue today. Could you please let me know, How did you solve this? This will really help. My statefulset pods are not able to ping each other using fqdn but through IP ping is happening.I have headless service as well which is working.

Comment: @Nish Do your headless service has any selector to select the pods? Or it is just a sevice with `.spec.clusterIP` set to `"None"` used as a requirement of a Statefulset?

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma, Below is my case. I have three stateful pods for three different tasks and three normal service for each on of them. These services are having selectors to select the respective pods. On top of these 3 service, one headless service is there whose reference I have given under each of the 3 staefulset pods, using `serviceName` attribue. One more thing there is one selector I have used which is common across all pods and headless service `tier: backend`

Comment: You can see this example: https://gist.github.com/shudipta/cc4376cfcf63fb026e6c7e52559fc69b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create `headless service` to be able to ping replicas from each to other within a `StatefulSet`. Something like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gov-svc-headless
  labels:
    your_label: your_value
spec:
  selector:
    your_label: your_value
  ports:
  - port: your_port
    name: transport
    protocol: TCP
  clusterIP: None <---
```

Note:

> With selectors For headless services that define selectors, the
>   endpoints controller creates Endpoints records in the API, and
>   modifies the DNS configuration to return A records (addresses) that
>   point directly to the Pods backing the Service.

Note:

> or headless services that do not define selectors, the endpoints
>   controller does not create Endpoints records. However, the DNS system
>   looks for and configures either:
>
> CNAME records for ExternalName-type services. A records for any
>   Endpoints that share a name with the service, for all other types.

More info: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services